# C++, parsing a string line with space as one unit

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing, delimiter

I'm writing a translator from my programming language which is a simplistic C++, and I have questions about parsing a line. In C++ we define some object as:

```
class Item{
    string Item;
    string Item2;
};
```

I would like to create the same object in my language using the keyword `add`:

```
add "Item Item", "Item2 Item2";
```

As you see, the `string` variable "Item*" may be a line with spaces.

But I need to parse it and make a command stack of arrays. In the example, I want to parse the line to make array of 3 like this: `[add, Item Item, Item2 Item2]`. So, I need to save the space between "Item Item" and count it as one string line while parsing, but still use space as delimiter between `add` and the first "Item*". How do I do that?

Comment: Count opening and closing quotes. If a quote is open, spaces are appended to last string. If a quote is not open, spaces are delimiters and get skipped.

Comment: Read it as a single line (using e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) then you have to parse the string in some other way. Removing the first white-space delimited word and the terminating semicolon should be easy. Then just split the rest at the comma, and remove each strings quotes.

Comment: Try Boost.Spirit. It surely helps you.

Comment: The `<iomanip>` header now has the manipulator `std::quoted()`

Comment: Also, I think you should read up on bison/flex or some similar tool if you want to create custom languages. Yacc/lex or bison/flex are really powerful, and fun to work with once you understand the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to break the lines into commands, this could be accomplished with [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then you'll want to break the command apart with [`quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted). (Note that `quoted` is C++14 only. So if you don't have that this solution will not work.)

An issue with this approach is that you are using spaces *and* commas as delimiters in your language. So you would have to extract the comma. But that could be accomplished with a simple `if` leaving you with something like:

```
vector<vector<string>> result;
string command;

while(getline(input, command, ';')) {
    istringstream i(command);
    string element;
    result.resize(result.size() + 1);

    while( i >> quoted(element)){
        if(element != ",") result.back().push_back(element);
    }
}
```

Where `input` is an `istringstream` with the commands.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FilZYw)

Comment: What if a quoted element contains a comma or a semicolon?

Comment: @ZDF In C++ the rules would be that's part of the quoted element. I'm assuming the same applies here.

Comment: I didn't notice `quoted`. Isn't  `quoted` part of c++14?

Comment: @ZDF Yup, good point I'll put a qualifier. Not everyone uses technology developed in the lat 2 years ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of Boost you can use the `split` function. I did not catch all the potential errors, but it gives the correct answer in fairly comprehensible code. What I did is to split the code on the quotes. Before the quotes there is the action, in between the first quotes is the first item, then comes the comma and in between the second set of quotes comes the second item:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

class Item_container
{
    public:
        Item_container(const std::string& s)
        {
            std::cout << "Input string: " << s << std::endl;

            std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
            boost::split(string_vector, s, boost::is_any_of("\""));

            // Below, error checking should be implemented
            stack.push_back(string_vector[0]);
            stack.push_back(string_vector[1]);
            stack.push_back(string_vector[3]);
        }

        std::vector<std::string> get_stack() const { return stack; }

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> stack;
};

int main()
{
    Item_container item_container("add \"Item Item\", \"Item2 Item2\";");

    for (auto &s : item_container.get_stack())
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little tokenizer. This is just a sample; it has no error checking, so it's likely to crash on unexpected input.  Include files are iostream, string, vector, and ctype.h.

```
enum st
{
    inSpace,
    inToken,
    inString
};

static st newstate(const char* p)
{
    if (isalpha(*p))
    {
        return inToken;
    }
    if ('"' == *p)
    {
        return inString;
    }
    return inSpace;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    char line[128];
    std::cin.getline(line, sizeof(line));
    st state = inSpace;
    char* p = line;
    char* ptok = nullptr; // Will point to the beginning of a token
    std::vector<std::string*> sym;

    while(*p)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case inSpace:
                while(isspace(*p) || (',' == *p))
                {
                    ++p;
                }
                state = newstate(p);
                break;

            case inString:
                ptok = p; // Token includes opening quote
                while('"' != *++p);
                sym.push_back(new std::string(ptok, p + 1));
                state = newstate(++p);
                break;

            case inToken:
                ptok = p;
                while(isalpha(*++p));
                sym.push_back(new std::string(ptok, p));
                state = newstate(p);
                break;

            default:
                std:: cout << "Error\n";
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; sym.size() > i; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Symbol #" << i + 1 << " = " << *(sym[i]) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer got downvoted. I tested it; it does run correctly. How does it fall short of being a good answer?